# Distinguish between two buttons in the same form method

Tags: java, servlets

I have two submit buttons inside the same form method (they need the same information) but each button has to do different stuff with the info, so my question is, when I'm in the response servlet how can i know which button from the request servlet triggered the form? (I'm working on java)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have an additional hidden value to indicate which button is clicked in the html form. Here is an example

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>What</title>
<script>
function fun1(num)
{
    if (num == 1)
    {
        document.getElementById('mybutton').value = "1";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('mybutton').value = "2";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="get" action="">
<input type="hidden" id="mybutton" name="mybutton" value="x"/>
<input type="submit" value="send" onclick="fun1(1)"/>
<input type="submit" value="send" onclick="fun1(2)"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now when you check the value of mybutton from servlet (req.getParameter()) method. That will indicate which button is clicked.

Thanks...